# Credit Card processing library iphone

Tags: iphone

I am looking for developing payment gateway in one of my commercial application. i want payment gateway which is having secure encryption, apple pay support, flexible charges,iOS and android sdk, etc. At this point i am trying to support only few countries like USA and Canada.

Can any one suggest me good payment gateway/processor here.

Comment: [Square](https://squareup.com/) already provides this service.  I don't think they provide an API, or that a different one exists publicly or privately.

Comment: Currently bookmyshow app provide such facility. i want to integrate same in my code. is any one having idea about same?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is also one of the good payment API i found.

[www.braintreegateway.com](http://www.braintreegateway.com)

ios source code here
https://github.com/braintree/braintree_ios_encryption_examples

Answer (score 1):

We're about to offer an API for this. Check out this page on our site: https://www.moblized.com/developers and we offering what you're looking for drop me an email at robb@moblized.com.

Update: We now have the API for adding credit card payments to your iPhone app. You can learn more here: http://developers.moblized.com/.

Comment: The links are dead.  Google did not help find corrections.  mobilized.com seems to still be active.  Just the developer stuff seems to be missing.

Answer (score 1):

I found the following payment options :

1. [Square](https://squareup.com/)
2. [Magtek](http://www.magtek.com/index.asp)
3. [Intuit](http://gopayment.com/)
4. [Mobilized](http://developers.moblized.com/)
5. [iMag](http://www.idtechproducts.com/products/mobile-readers/105.html)
6. [Paypal](https://cms.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/?cmd=_render-content&content_ID=developer/howto_gateway_payflowpro)
7. [Chase Paymentech](http://www.chasepaymentech.com/mobile_payments.html)
8. [GoEmerchant](http://www.goemerchant.com/mterminal.htm)
9. [MobileAuthorize](http://mobileauthorize.com/iphone.html)
10. [Planetauthorize](http://www.planetauthorize.com/iphone.html)

Comment: http://www.goemerchant.com/mterminal.htm

Comment: http://mobileauthorize.com/iphone.html

Comment: http://www.planetauthorize.com/iphone.html

Answer (score 1):

If you're living in the USA, there is Stripe (https://stripe.com/), no withdrawal fees but only works for USA customers :(

If you're willing to pay $4.00 withdrawl fee to collect your money, you can use ZooZ (http://www.zooz.com/) , works in a number of countries.

Both these options don't require any hardware. Users just tap a button and your own app gets the user to enter their credit card details. Both solutions offer a website to manage all transactions too, very user friendly.