# Credit card payment for passes in ios

Tags: ios, payment, passbook

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Accept payment on ios apps?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6481517/accept-payment-on-ios-apps)

Can i allow user to pay for their passes in my app by using their credit card instead of apple in app purchase

Comment: Please, use the search before asking something that has already been asked: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6481517/accept-payment-on-ios-apps

Comment: Thanks you, i read it, but was kind of confused, since passes are digital