# About The Paypal payment in iphone? (description is below)

Tags: iphone, ios5, paypal, paypal-sandbox

i m new in iphone programming and i m very confused in paypal..

paypal payment with credit card without Login into paypal and without paypal account.i want to make app where i want to enter credit card numbers and other info of credit card and purchase thing from my app.what i have to do guyzz..help me out.. thank x in advance.

Comment: check this thread. making direct payments from your app is not permitted. http://stackoverflow.com/a/6481723/919049

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set SOLUTIONTYPE=Sole of your SetExpressCheckoutRequestDetails object to enable the user to do the transactions without having a Paypal account

e,g. If the objSetExpressCheckoutRequestDetails is object of class SetExpressCheckoutRequestDetails in your code then add line

```
objSetExpressCheckoutRequestDetails.SolutionType=SOLE;
```

in your code wherever you are initializing your paypal object

Answer (score 1):

I think it's help full to you.Can you try This below reference link.

[Paypal sand box using ios](http://haifa.baluyos.net/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=64%3aobjective-c-ios-paypal-integration-tutorial&catid=1%3aprogramming&Itemid=5)