# integration paypal with ios

Tags: ios, paypal

I am developing an application where I need to integrate payments with PayPal, I have downloaded the [PayPal iOS SDK](http://www.github.com/paypal/PayPal-iOS-SDK),
everything works perfectly with the sandbox but now I do not know how to switch the mode for production.
any help would be apprediated.

Comment: Apple refuses any in-app payment methods besides their own. Don't even try.

Comment: It depends what the payments are for: http://stackoverflow.com/a/6481793/620197

Comment: The list of live end points can be found here: https://www.x.com/developers/paypal/documentation-tools/api-endpoints, and the full guide to go live: https://www.x.com/developers/paypal/documentation-tools/going-live-with-your-application

Comment: @Linuxios That's not the case, seeing at how Apple prohibits you from using IAP from *physical goods*. Lots of apps use alternative payment methods for things where IAP is not allowed.

Answer (score 9):

The PayPal SDK is fine if you go for physical goods.
Regarding your question: to switch to live you just need to remove this line

```
[PayPalPaymentViewController setEnvironment:PayPalEnvironmentNoNetwork];
```

Answer (score 6):

The sample code you are probably following in the [iOS integration docs](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/integration/mobile/ios-integration-guide/) sets the environment to `PayPalEnvironmentNoNetwork`:

```c
// Start out working with the test environment! 
// When you are ready, remove this line to switch to live.
[PayPalPaymentViewController setEnvironment:PayPalEnvironmentNoNetwork];
```

You could just remove that line to go live, since the default is `PayPalEnvironmentProduction`.

However, you probably want to test your integration before going live by changing the environment to `PayPalEnvironmentSandbox`:

```c
[PayPalPaymentViewController setEnvironment:PayPalEnvironmentSandbox];
```

You can create sandbox accounts over [here](https://developer.paypal.com/).

When switching to production, rather than deleting the line, it is safer and clearer to be explicit:

```c
[PayPalPaymentViewController setEnvironment:PayPalEnvironmentProduction];
```

See also [PayPalPaymentViewController.h documentation on environments](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/integration/mobile/ios-integration-guide/).

Answer (score 1):

```
//for testing    
[PayPalPaymentViewController setEnvironment:self.environment]; 

//for Paypal live app than it set  in our app code  
[PayPalPaymentViewController setEnvironment:PayPalEnvironmentProduction];   

//check in Paypal sandbox account
[PayPalPaymentViewController setEnvironment:PayPalEnvironmentSandbox];
```

Answer (score 1):

In `PaymentMethodViewController`

1. Replace **PayPalEnvironmentSandbox** with **PayPalEnviromentProduction** of `kPayPalEnvironment` global variable.
2. Set *live credentials* of paypal account.