# How to avoid IAP 30% charges ( IOS Application ) on subscription?

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase

I am working on a matrimonial IOS app which allows users to register as a free member. There is some content on the application for which users need to become a premium member by purchasing a membership package. Each membership package is for a limited period and after that, they need to renew their membership again. Now, IOS is restricting to use IAP only which charges 30%.

Is there any way to avoid this IOS charges? Or any alternative solution where I need t pay minimum charges.

Comment: You can have the users subscribe through a website but your app cannot link to the website, refer to the website or provide the website URL. Apple's commission drops to 20% after a user has been a subscriber for 1 year.

Comment: If you're allowed to avoid IAPs depends on the content. In your case it could be possible that you don't need to use IAPs. In that case you can do what Paulw11 wrote. See this answer for details about Apples rules for IAPs usage: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6481793.

Answer (score 0):

You can check great example for using third-party payment for subscription in Netflix & Spotify iOS App. In Netflix you need to signup from website and eroll to your required subscription plan, and in spotify you need to subscribe from website